# Loops não mantêm os valores

Tags: java, loop, while

Olá! Estou tentando desenvolver um programa simples que faça um cálculo de contabilidade automático, porém, a condição dentro do for(while, do while, if / else, qualquer uma) não mantêm seus valores. A repetição é executada 12~13 vezes e em todas não se muda o valor de saída. Porque exatamente os valores dentro dos loops são zerados e exibidos como se fosse feito só uma conta?

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
      int x;
      double percentual=0.005, ValorSaida, ValorPercentual=0;
      x=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite o valor depositado mensalmente"));

      for(int meses=0; meses<=12; meses++)
      {  

       ValorPercentual=x*percentual;
       ValorSaida=x+ValorPercentual;
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ""+ValorSaida+" "+ValorPercentual);

      }     


    }
```

Comment: Tens de igual o `x` a alguma coisa, senão nunca vais ter saída...

Comment: Esclarecendo o cometário do CesarMiguel: a seguir a `JOptionsPane.ShowMess.....` iguala `x` a `ValorSaida`

Answer (score 2):

Toda vez q o código executa o loop, ele sob-escreve os valores tente assim:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
      int x;
      double percentual=0.005, ValorSaida, ValorPercentual=0;
      x=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite o valor depositado mensalmente"));

      for(int meses=0; meses<=12; meses++){  

          ValorPercentual += x*percentual;
          ValorSaida += x+ValorPercentual;

      }     
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ""+ValorSaida+" "+ValorPercentual);

    }
```

Você tem q somar os valores --> com o `+=`

Comment: O problema de colocar a exibição fora do Loop, é que ele vai exibir só o de 12 meses. Mantenha a exibição dentro se for necessário exibir cada um dos meses. Sugiro também que comece com 1 ao invés de 0.

Comment: Até concordo com o showMessage fora do loop - e já peço perdão por isso.
Mas se ela iniciar o valorPercentual com 1 isso vai alterar o valor final. Exemplo: 1ª vez q entra no loop o valorPercentual vai ser-> 1 +(x*0.005) e o resultado estaria errado.

Comment: Bem notado... falha minha de ter visado apenas os meses e a exibição.

Comment: Obrigado! Era só isso mesmo "+=", tentei muitos códigos/métodos e era só isso.É um problema criado por mim mesmo, a localização da exibição não é tão importante assim, sequer decidi onde coloca-lo.